# How can I extend FutureTask and ensure reference to Callable is released?

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have as custom ExecutorService that contains within it a ScheduledExecutorService that can be used to interrupt tasks submitted to the ExecutorSerice if they are taking too long, ive put the complet class at the end of this post.

This was working okay except that sometimes the interrupt caused a problem in itself so instead I added the a volatile boolean **cancel** flag to a new CanceableTask class and made them subclass this so that they could check for and stop themselves cleanly if they the boolean had been sent to true. Note their is an instance of boolean in each class submitted to the executor service precisley so that long running task can be cancelled without cancelling other tasks.

However a **FutureTask** is passed as a parameter to the **beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)** and this does not give access to the Callable class so my Timeout code cannot set the cancel flag.

I got round this by overriding the **newTaskFor** method to return a class that just provide a reference to the Callable

```
public class FutureCallable<V> extends FutureTask<V>
{
    private Callable<V> callable;
    public FutureCallable(Callable<V> callable) {
        super(callable);
        this.callable = callable;
    }
    public Callable<V> getCallable() {
        return callable;
    }
}
```

and everything was working great, or so I thought.

Unfortunately my application was now using more and more memory as new tasks were submitted to the ExecutorService and eventually running out of memory, when I profile the application I find that there is a Thread stack local reference to all the FutureCallables, even after the task has completed and because the FutureCallable has a reference to the class that was being run it uses alot of memory.

When I look at the code for FutureTask that (FutureCallable extends) there is a comment for the private Callable reference that says

```
/** The underlying callable; nulled out after running */
```

So how could I improve my FutureCallable to null out its reference to Callable ?
Or why is there a reference to The FutureCallable maintained after the task has completed.

I have confirmed that if I comment out the newTaskFor method there is no excessive memory usage, but unfortunately I cannot cancel the class then.

Complete Class is:

```
public class TimeoutThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private final long timeout;
    private final TimeUnit timeoutUnit;

    private final static int WAIT_BEFORE_INTERRUPT = 10000;
    private final static int WAIT_BEFORE_STOP      = 10000;


    private final ScheduledExecutorService timeoutExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    //Map Task to the Future of the Timeout Task that could be used to interrupt it
    private final ConcurrentMap<Runnable, ScheduledFuture> runningTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<Runnable, ScheduledFuture>();

    public long getTimeout()
    {
        return timeout;
    }

    public TimeUnit getTimeoutUnit()
    {
        return timeoutUnit;
    }

    public TimeoutThreadPoolExecutor(int workerSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory, long timeout, TimeUnit timeoutUnit)
    {
        super(workerSize, workerSize, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), threadFactory);
        MainWindow.logger.severe("Init:"+workerSize+":Timeout:"+timeout+":"+timeoutUnit);
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.timeoutUnit = timeoutUnit;
    }

    public TimeoutThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, long timeout, TimeUnit timeoutUnit) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.timeoutUnit = timeoutUnit;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> FutureCallable<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new FutureCallable<T>(callable);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        timeoutExecutor.shutdownNow();
        return super.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        if(timeout > 0) {
            //Schedule a task to interrupt the thread that is running the task after time timeout starting from now
            final ScheduledFuture<?> scheduled = timeoutExecutor.schedule(new TimeoutTask(t, r), timeout, timeoutUnit);

            //Add Mapping
            runningTasks.put(r, scheduled);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {

        //AfterExecute will be called after the task has completed, either of its own accord or because it
        //took too long and was interrupted by corresponding timeout task
        //Remove mapping and cancel timeout task
        ScheduledFuture timeoutTask = runningTasks.remove(r);
        if(timeoutTask != null) {
            timeoutTask.cancel(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void terminated()
    {
        //All tasks have completed either naturally or via being cancelled by timeout task so close the timeout task
        MainWindow.logger.severe("---Shutdown TimeoutExecutor");
        timeoutExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Interrupt or possibly stop the thread
     *
     */
    class TimeoutTask implements Runnable {
        private final       Thread thread;
        private             Callable c;

        public TimeoutTask(Thread thread, Runnable c) {
            this.thread = thread;
            if(c instanceof FutureCallable)
            {
                this.c = ((FutureCallable) c).getCallable();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            String msg = "";
            if (c != null)
            {
                if (c != null && c instanceof CancelableTask)
                {
                    MainWindow.logger.severe("+++Cancelling " + msg + " task because taking too long");
                    ((CancelableTask) c).setCancelTask(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    public abstract class CancelableTask  extends ExecutorServiceEnabledAnalyser
    {
        private volatile boolean cancelTask = false;

        public boolean isCancelTask() {
            return cancelTask;
        }

        public void setCancelTask(boolean cancelTask) {
            this.cancelTask = cancelTask;
        }

        CancelableTask(final MainWindow start, boolean isSelectedRecords, boolean isUseRowSelection)
        {
            super(start, isSelectedRecords, isUseRowSelection);
        }

        CancelableTask(final MainWindow start, List<MetadataChangedWrapper> songs)
        {
            super(start, songs );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this `ThreadLocal`? I find it strange and hard to believe what you are saying, that it keeps references to all tasks ever run, even after completion. If this is the case, it should run out of memory eventually even without your overriding (the task itself uses some memory albeit, maybe less than what your callable takes, but still not zero).

Anyway, you can override the `done` method on your `FutureCallable` to null out the wrapped object after execution.

Comment: Ah, its not Thread local but Thread stacklocal but I wasnt clear what thread it was Ive now realised it is the thread submitting to the ExecutorService and it because i store the returned future i.e              futures.add(es.submit(new CorrectFromMusicBrainzWorker(this, stats, matchKey, songs)));
            count++;
        }, removing this seems to have fixed it but for good measure I will take your advice and also override done()